# Need Comment Link Help

Tags: comments

I am interested in adding a comment form at the end of my posts from the home page.  I use Disqus and the comment form shows up when you click onto the actual post itself but not after a post on the home page.

At the very least, moving the comment link from the title area to the end of each post (on the home page) would be great, as it's currently hard for people to find where to comment.

I'm using the free platform theme by pagelines.  My url is www.trinketsofthought.com.  I'm not the most techinal/code-y type of person, so help in the form of dummed down terms would be fabulous.  I greatly appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

This is a *caveat emptor* solution, because the comments template is **not intended** to be displayed on archive-index pages.

To display the comments template on archive index pages, you need to ensure that the [appropriate template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) (e.g. `index.php`, `archive.php`, etc.) calls [`<?php comments_template(); ?>`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) at the appropriate place *inside* the Loop.

If you need to know what the "appropriate place *inside* the Loop" is, take a look at the markup in, e.g. `single.php`.